# Pressure cooking green beens

Tags: food-safety, storage-method

I am canning my green beans and I have my camp chef in the garage that I am pressuring them on. So I go distracted and didn't realize they had already met their 13 lbs and had been there for... I don't know how long, so I guessed. Now I am nervous I didn't pressure them long enough. I cooked them 10 more minutes from the time I realized they were already pressuring. They look fine. Should I pressure cook them again to make sure? AND, what if I don't re-pressure them, will they make us sick?

Comment: can you be more specific, what do you mean by "they were pressuring". Do you mean cooking in a pressure cooker placed on a camp chef?

Answer (score 1):

Looking fine isnt enough to tell you that it is safe. 
The bare minimum process time in the pressure canner for pints is 20 minutes (25 minutes for quarts). if you only processed for 10 minutes that you timed and an unknown length of time before that then I'm not sure if anyone can reliably tell you if it is safe or not.

To be perfectly safe as well as confident in your assumption of safety then it would probably be best to just reprocess according to the times in the tables from the link below.
http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/beans_snap_italian.html

**edit:** I noticed that you said pressure cook and not pressure can at the end of your question. There is a difference between pressure cookers and pressure canners and a cooker is usually not sufficient as a canner. Make sure that what you are using is actually a canner - some manufacturers incorrectly label their cookers as cooker/canners.
There is more detailed information at the links below:

Why pressure cookers are not sufficient for canning: http://nchfp.uga.edu/publications/nchfp/factsheets/pressurecookers.html

More information on using pressure canners:
http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/general/recomm_canners.html

(links are okay here... right?)

Comment: Yes, links are ok *if they provide additional information* to the already existing answer. Rule of thumb: Imagine the links suddenly went bad. Is your answer still a complete answer? In your case, you used links just as one should here, IMHO. Wouldn't hurt to add another sentence or two about the information given by the links, but that's entirely up to you.